# Andorid Compose Blur Drop Down Menu

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I have a figma design for drop down menu. I'm trying to do this with compose in android. But I couldn't make the background blur effect in the drop down menu.

[image: Figma Design]
[image: Drop Down Menu properties]

```
@Composable
fun DropDown(
    projects: List<String>,
    onClickProject: () -> Unit
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val valueNameText = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    val icon = if (expanded)
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_arrow_up)
    else
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_arrow_down)

    TextFieldSimple(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .fillMaxWidth(1f)
            .padding(top = 16.dp)
            .clickable {
                expanded = !expanded
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        textValue = selectedText,
        placeholder = "Gender",
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
        textColor = Color.White,
        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
        errorText = "Error",
        onValueChange = {
            selectedText = it
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(
                icon, null,
                Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded },
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            )
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
        enable = false
    )

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.copy(surface = Color(0xF220294F)),
    ) {
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() })
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = Color.Transparent)
                    .blur(radius = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Column {
                    projects.forEachIndexed { index, label ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            onClick = {
                                onClickProject()
                                selectedText = label
                                expanded = false
                            },
                            text = {
                                Text(
                                    color = Color.White,
                                    text = label
                                )
                            }
                        )
                        if (projects.size -1 != index)
                            Divider(color = BlueGrey200)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

By design, I made a drop down menu in this way, but I could not blur the background. How can I do this, is there a solution?

so we want to add blur to the drop down menu background
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Modifier.blur` is only supported on Android 12 and later. it does nothing on earlier versions. there's no easy way to make true blur there.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDukhov, I'm looking for something that works at least on android 7 and later